# How to make tree estimators to have splitter parameter random?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I want to change the splitter parameter for half of the trees used for my random forest classifier.
However, if I don't train (fit) them, the estimators aren't accessible.
For instance, what I wanted was something like below:

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
for tree in rfc.estimators_:
    if np.random.rand() <= 0.5:
         tree.splitter = 'random'
```

Is there any possible way to achieve this?
('this' referring to 'making half of the tree estimators to have splitter parameter 'random' rather than its default 'best')

EDIT:
After some searching and from the help of the comments, I tried defining a non-trained random forest (or any tree ensemble for that matter) and did the following.

```
rfc_etc_merge = RandomForestClassifier()
rfc_etc_merge.estimators_ = rfc.estimators_ + etc.estimators_
rfc_etc_merge.n_classes_ = rfc.n_classes_
rfc_etc_merge.n_outputs_ = rfc.n_outputs_
rfc_etc_merge.classes_ = rfc.classes_
```

It seems to work fine without any errors (for predictions or probability prediction) but would this method be actually error-free?

Comment: I think, your question can be generalized to: _How to make tree estimators to have splitter parameter `random` rather than its default `best`_. The issue with setting it for a half of trees only can be addressed by training **two** classifiers with different arguments and them merging them together (by averaging predicted probabilities), as RF trees are independent (assuming that you use different random seeds) and thus can be stacked together.

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi I not familiar with the functions of '.fit' and '.predict' of the ensemble classifiers. Can you elaborate on how to merge them without causing any internal issues? (I'm worried that I might cause problems without triggering any syntax errors in which case I won't even know if I'm doing something wrong)

Comment: well, you instantiate `clf1` and `clf2` (with different random seeds and parameters). You train them on the same data. Then you do `pred_prob =  clf1.(predict_proba(X_test) + clf.predict_proba(X_test))/2`. I believe, that's what RFC does internally to make an average decision based on the trained N trees, as is stated [in the last paragraph in this section of the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#random-forests). If you need to have binary predictions you can get them by `pred_prob > 0.5` transformed into ints

Comment: Why do you want to do  this?

Comment: @BertKellerman I came across a stacking algorithm called Forward Thinking (https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07366) where the authors provided the code through github. However, I'm not sure whether it's because of the old version they used but it had the bit of code above (my question) which I couldn't run.